# How is the result of openssl_sign() encoded?

Tags: php

[The docs about `openssl_sign()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) say that the signature is returned in the passed string argument. My question is - how is it encoded? Base64, Hex-string, anything else?

I don't have php installed and I have to use this  PHP code I was given simply in order to verify whether my Java implementation is correct, so don't ask me "have you tried it" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be encoded at all:

```
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo $signature;
```

produces:

```
p}+C&3�\˅��u�gh��X������j��Yx���e�?�l�j��\�a/d�3}��t�l�w�
```

or:

```
00000000  05 70 7d 2b 43 26 33 d1  5c cb 85 ff b0 75 c6 67  |.p}+C&3.\....u.g|
00000010  68 d2 d6 58 87 8f 02 f2  bc e5 f9 6a ff c4 59 78  |h..X.......j..Yx|
00000020  bc 85 b4 13 65 fe 3f 00  d0 15 6c e7 6a b1 93 5c  |....e.?...l.j..\|
00000030  88 61 2f 64 f8 33 7d b1  ad 74 01 e1 6c d9 77 c4  |.a/d.3}..t..l.w.|
00000040
```